# Schema compare not updating target

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

Im using sql server data tools, i have a solution with my database schema and im triying to update it by doing an schema compare with my db, the problem is that its says "updated correctly" but no changes are made to my solution, has anyone had the same problem?

PD. Block on data loss is unchecked
PD2. Generate script button is disabled

Comment: You're pushing changes from the db to your solution? I don't think this is supported by schema compare. Schema compare is for pushing changes from your solution to the db.

Comment: @Keith Yes this can be done, it works both ways, you con also compare with .dacpac files and snapshots created from your solution

Comment: From time to time I am getting the same problem when updating database from project. In my case I have to do: schema compare, Update - nothing is updated, schema compare second time, update and then it works.

Comment: @scar80 Yes a think it might be a bug or something, after a couple of times (half day trying) It worked.

Comment: If you use Entity Model, then you have to update the Model. I updated db, but forgot to update the Model, and got this error.